# Number of digits in $1 \ldots n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms

Let $n$ be a positve integer. Consider the task of printing all the numbers from $1$ to $n$. For example, 512 has three digits.

When $n$ is small,the task can be completed quickly; when $n$ is large it can take a long time.

How many digits does it take to print these numbers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think your title of the question is a bit different from your question.Speaking of the question,have you any knowledge of characteristic-mantissa yet?

Comment: "*For example, 512 has three digits*" $\;-\;$ All numbers from $\,100\,$ to $\,1000-1\,$ have three decimal digits. And it so happens that $\,1000=10^3\,$.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-digits-of-a-number/

Answer (score 1):

A whole sequence of $k$ digits numbers (from $10^{k-1}$ to $10^k-1$) totals $9k\,10^{k-1}$ digits. If $n$ has $m$ digits, the last incomplete sequence totals $m(n-10^{m-1}+1)$ digits.

Hence,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}9k\,10^{k-1}+m(n-10^{m-1}+1)=m(n+1)-\frac{10^m-1}9$$

with $m:=\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... Let's start with $n=512$.  You must print all the numbers from $1...9$.  They each have $1$ digit and there are $9$ of them.  So that is $9$ digits.  The you must print all the numbers from $10$ to $99$. There are $90$ of those and they have $2$ digits so that is $90\times 2 = 180$ more digits.  Then all the numbers from $100$ to $999$ have three digits.  But we are only going up to $512$.  $1...99$ had fewer than $3$ digits but all the rest have $3$ so we have $512-99$ numbers with three digits.  That is $3\times (512-99)=3\times 413 = 1239$ more digits.  So we needed $9+180+1239$ digits to print all the numbers to $512$.

We can generalize this.  If $n = a_k\times 10^k + a_{k-1}\times 10^{k-1} + .... + a_1\times 10 + a_0$, a $k+1$ digit number, we can do this in two steps.

First all the digits from $1$ to $10^k - 1$.  There are $9$ one digit numbers and $90$ two digit numbers and $900$ three digit numbers etc. So that meas we have $9\times 1 + 90\times 2 + 900 \times 3 + ..... + 9\times 10^{i-1} \times i + ..... 9\times 10^{k-1}\times k$ digits.

Then we need to figure out have many $k+1$ digit numbers there are between $10^k$ to $n$.  And that is $n-(10^k-1)=n-10^k + 1$.  And the each have $(k+1)$ digits so that is $(k+1)(n-10^k-1)$ digits.

So in total you need $9\times 1 + 90\times 2 + 900 \times 3 + ..... + 9\times 10^{i-1} \times i + ..... 9\times 10^{k-1}\times k+(k+1)(n-10^k-1)$.

.....

Now an interesting thing happens when we try to calculate $9\times 1 + 90\times 2 + 900 \times 3 + ..... + 9\times 10^{i-1} \times i + ..... 9\times 10^{k-1}\times k$

$9\times 1 = 9$
$9\times 1 + 2\times 90 = 189$
$9\times 1 + 2\times 90 + 3\times 900 = 2889$
$9\times 1 + 2\times 90 + 3\times 900 + 4\times 9000 = 38889$

etc.

Why.... and if this pattern holds we should have $9\times 1 + 2\times 90 + 3\times 900 + 4\times 9000 + ..... + 9\times 900000000 = \color{blue}8888888889$ but what happens after that? is $9\times 1 + 2\times 90 + 3\times 900 + 4\times 9000 + ..... + 9\times 900000000 + 10\times 9000000000 = 988888888889$?

Well, $9\times 1 + 90\times 2 + 900 \times 3 + ..... + 9\times 10^{i-1} \times i + ..... 9\times 10^{k-1}\times k=$

$(10-1)\times 1 + (10-1)\times 10\times 2 + (10-1)\times 100\times 3 + ..... + (10-1)\times 10^{k-1}\times k =$

$(10 + 2\times 100 + 3\times 1000+ ...... +k\times 10^k) - (1 + 2\times 10 + 3\times 100 + ..... + k\times 10^{k-1})=$

$-1 + (1-2)\times 10 + (2-3)\times 100 + (3-4)\times 1000 + ..... + ((k-1)-k)\times 10^{k-1} + 10^{k}k =$

$-1\times (1+10+100+ ..... +10^{k-1})+k\times 10^k=$

$k\underbrace{0000.....0}_{k} - \underbrace{11111....1}_k = [k-1]\underbrace{8888....8}9$.

If you want the *proper* way to right this number it is

$\underbrace{1111.....1}_k = \frac{\underbrace{9999....999}_k}9=\frac {10^k-1}9$

So $-1\times (1+10+100+ ..... +10^{k-1})+k\times 10^k=k\times 10^k - \frac{10^k-1}9 -1$.

So the number of digits we print for  $n = a_k\times 10^k + a_{k-1}\times 10^{k-1} + .... + a_1\times 10 + a_0$ is

$k\times 10^k - \frac{10^k-1}9 -1 + (k+1)(n - 10^k +1)$.

Where $10^k \le n < 10^{k+1}$.